# Cannot Call a Flash Function from Javascript

Tags: javascript, flash, function, externalinterface

I've been all over here and can't find an answer. I have a .swf sitting in an HTML page and I am trying to call a function inside of it from javascript. I can talk out from flash to the javascript but I can't get it to talk back in. I know I am targeting the object properly because I use console.log() on it and confirms what it is targeting.

I'm triggering the test from flash, calling a javascript function from inside the .swf, and having that function call the internal Flash function.

Flash Code:

```
//adds callback
ExternalInterface.addCallback("sendToFlash", flashTalkedTo);

//function called by the callback
public function flashTalkedTo():void{
    //runs another function in javascript to log a string
    ExternalInterface.call("callMe")
}

//calls javascript that tries to talk to Flash
ExternalInterface.call("catchFromFlash")
```

Javascript Code:

```
//function called by Flash that initiates
function catchFromFlash(){
    talkToFlash()
}

//function that tries to talk to flash
function talkToFlash(){
    document.getElementById('Noodleverse').sendToFlash()
}

//function called by Flash in the end to confirm call made
function callMe(){
    console.log("Call Me")
}
```

Any help works, thanks!

Comment: which HTML element has the `Noodleverse` id? Showing the rough HTML structure would help.

Comment: And also doing a `console.log(document.getElementById('Noodleverse'))` inside `talkToFlash` to confirm that it actually runs, and that it finds the correct element.

Answer (score 1):

Flash, and plugins in general, are a little bit fiddly. They don't behave quite like normal elements, and their functions don't behave quite like normal functions. For example, you can't save the element into a value and call a function from that. You also need to be careful because in some browsers the `object` is used and in others the `embed` is used.

The best way to call a function is to use swfobject (https://code.google.com/p/swfobject/) to abstract everything. Personally though, I use this (based on experience, maybe somebody can offer improvements):

HTML:

```
<object id="myplugin" ...>
    ...
    <embed name="myplugin" ... />
</object>
```

JavaScript:

```
var o1=document.myplugin;
if(o1&&!!o1.myFlashFunction){
    return document.myplugin.myFlashFunction(); // DO NOT USE o1 here. It will fail.
}
var o2=window.myplugin;
if(o2&&!!o2.myFlashFunction){
    return window.myplugin.myFlashFunction(); // DO NOT USE o2 here
}
```

The first case (`document`) is for most new browsers. For example, Chrome will find the `embed` object. The second (`window`) is for IE and finds the `object` (IE, at least old IE, ignores `embed`). I'm not 100% sure the second is needed, because IE might also work with `document`, so call that voodoo code. Also `window.myplugin` will give an array of all matching elements in Chrome, FireFox, etc. (but we expect those to already be taken care of)

Comment: I've done the console.log() on the piece making the call and it works fine. I'm hoping to not use SWFObject since I tried it already and it gave me layout problems.

Comment: @user2225288 so... are you still having a problem? Did you try the code I posted?